# Why won't Lync 2013 connect when I am on an office network, but if I tether it to my iPhone, it works fine?

Tags: certificate, windows-10-preview, lync, lync-2013

If I connect to the network via the office network (either office Wifi or ethernet), Lync 2013 will not connect.  It states:

[image]

However, if I connect my laptop to either the Wifi network from the neighboring office or tether to my iPhone, it connects perfectly fine.

I should point out that this is a Windows 10 laptop and everything works great except for this.
The in-house tech support tried installing all kinds of certificates, but none of them resolved the problem.

I should further note that when this laptop had Win8.1, Lync connected fine on any network.

Answer (score 0):

The Lync client uses two different server addresses, one for internal use when you are on your domain network and one external for use when connected to any other network like the tethered phone or public wifi. You probably have a correct certificate for the external server address but not for the internal. Check the configured addresses and that you get the correct certificates for them both. The addresses can be found under the Advanced... option in the Change login address in the File menu.